# JavaScript File Download with Blob

Tags: javascript

I am trying to download the file from JS. The server send the Stream in application/octect-stream. In JS I am doing like:

```
var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = downloadUrl;
a.download = filename;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
```

But when open up the downloaded file, it's just empty. The files could be jpeg, pdf, txt and other mime types.

Comment: my download lib accepts blobs: https://github.com/rndme/download that said, does this.response have your contents?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes this.response is the stream I am getting from server. I tried yours as well but same problem. If I just display in the browser it comes up. I can see the pdf or images but when I want to download. I get nothing.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I found the answer, I was missing responseType: 'arraybuffer'. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting cross browser file downloads isn't easy. I recommend you use `file-saver`.

Link: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Example:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

export function download(blobResponse) {
    const blob = blobResponse.body;
    const disposition = blobResponse.headers.get('content-disposition');
    let filename = disposition.replace(/"/g, '').substring(disposition.indexOf('=') + 1);
    saveAs(blob, filename);
}
```